# Can there be fields inside fields in Ingress?

Tags: ingress

If I were to make a larger field that entirely encompassed one or more smaller fields of the other faction, what happens?

Do the smaller fields "break"? If they do, do I get AP for that?
Can the other faction still own the portals inside my field?

Answer (score 15):

You can create bigger fields around smaller one (until the links do not cross). The MU will also be credited twice (even with fields belonging to different factions)

According to [this documentation](http://ingressportal.com/research/control-fields/):

> If one control region fully encloses another control region, both
>   regions get credit for all the mind units they enclose.

Edit :

**Rules about links and fields :**

- links cannot cross, never : `It would be bad.` (Dr E. Spengler ;) ) (neither a green link can cross a blue link).
- you can create fields inside other fields, but only if you link some portals making the outer field to an inner portal ([source](http://awayoflife0.blogspot.fr/2012/12/ingress-creating-fields-within-fields.html)). You can't make a field completely inside another...Yet you can make fields completely around other fields.

Comment: But once you have done that, no one can create links inside that field anymore, even if the new links don't intersect with existing ones. We had to learn than painfully, yesterday.

Comment: @Sentry : this is not totally right, I edited my answer to add some precisions.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is the exception to the "no new inner fields" rule.

Answer (score 1):

You now can create fields within fields:
1. Friendly portal inside existing friendly field.
2. Clear path to portal from at least two of the anchor points to the field.
3. Link from each anchor point that has a clear path to the portal.

Comment: I think this was always possible - the key point is that the *source* portal of the link must be one of the corners of the existing field.

Answer (score 0):

Links can cross, as seen by this image:

[image]

Comment: See a timelapse of this image happening: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/ab2dyr/ingress_harmony_art_with_crossed_links/ .This only happens when the timing is precise.